# Symbol like '\propto' but inverted

Tags: symbols

I'm looking for a symbol like `\propto` but rotated 180 degrees (or even better, a symbol like the [pink ribbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pink_ribbon) rotated in -90 degrees) but can't find it anywhere.

Im looking for somthing similar to the following picture:

[image: propto rotated 180 degrees]

(again, if it resembles the pink ribbon rotated moreso than an chopped infinity, it's better but anything of this form will do). How could I make one such symbol?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use commands from the package `graphicx` to do the rotation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand{\proptoinverse}{\mathrel{\mskip1mu\reflectbox{$\propto$}\mskip-1mu}}

\begin{document}

$A \propto B$

$A \proptoinverse B$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: 1) `\propto` is `\mathrel`, not `\mathbin`, check [its definition in latex2e, `fontdef.dtx`](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/blob/77a02087b2ffcfe942bb31d88a1e364a185c5999/base/fontdef.dtx#L1068). 2) `graphicx` has a `\reflectbox{<text>}` that does x-axis reflection and can be seen as an abbreviation for both `\rotatebox[origin=c]{180}{<text>}` and `\scalebox{-1}[1]{<text>}`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Thank you, fixed!

Comment: Sorry but what's `\mskip1mu` for? It seemed to me now `$A \proptoinverse B$` is 1mu wider than `$A \propto B$`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Compared with `\propto`, the rotated version seems a little bit to the left, so I added `\mskip1mu` for adjustment. I thought `\mskip-1mu` should be able to correct this.

Answer (score 3):

Certainly not supported by all fonts, but Unicode actually does have a “Reminder Ribbon“ (U+1F397) character:

Try this (compiled with `LuaLaTeX`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}

\setmainfont{Noto Sans}
\newfontfamily{\emojifont}{NotoEmoji-Regular.ttf}   
% Get it here: https://fonts.google.com/noto/specimen/Noto+Emoji

\begin{document}
\begin{center}

    \Large Behold my regular ribbon … \newline
    \fontsize{65}{80}\selectfont    % U+1F397   REMINDER RIBBON
    {\emojifont\symbol{"1F397}}

    \Large … and my newly rotated pink ribbon! \newline
    \fontsize{65}{80}\selectfont    % U+1F397   REMINDER RIBBON
    \vspace{-5cm}\par
    \rotatebox{270}{\emojifont\color{pink}{\symbol{"1F397}}}

\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question OP wanted 180 not 90 degree rotation, for the opposite relation,like < relates to>

Comment: He wanted 180° for `∝` sure, but ``already has a 90° difference that must be made up for. Either way, correcting the rotation should be trivial.